# How to fix error: Too many indices for array

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I get the error on "formattedData = run.formatData(temp)" "IndexError: too many indices for array"

```
   data = np.insert(data,0,scrape())
   data = data.astype(np.float)

   print(data)

   temp = data

   formattedData = run.formatData(temp)
```

Here is the function referenced

```
def formatData(a):


    sequence_length = 4
    result = []
    for index in range(len(a) - sequence_length):
        result.append(a[index: index + sequence_length])

    result = normalise_windows(result)

    result = np.array(result)

    x = result[:, :-1]
    y = result[:, -1]


    x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], 1, 1))

    return x
```

Here is normalize_window

```
def normalise_windows(window_data):
    normalised_data = []
    for window in window_data:
        try:
            normalised_window = [((float(p) / float(window[0])) - 1) for p in window]
        except ValueError:
            normalised_window = [((float(p) / float(window[0])) - 1) for p in window]
        normalised_data.append(normalised_window)
    return normalised_data
```

Full error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carson/mlTechnicalAnalysis/autoTrader.py", line 71, in <module>
    scheduler.add_job(main(data), 'cron', hour='9-16', minute='*/5')
  File "/Users/carson/mlTechnicalAnalysis/autoTrader.py", line 54, in main
    formattedData = run.formatData(temp)
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours now and I can't get anywhere. i've tried making the array floats instead of strings and completely started over the formatData function from a base I know works on another set of code. I appreciate all the help I can get from y'all. Thanks so much

Comment: Hey @Carson P, can we see the full error message/stack trace?

Comment: this is an unpacking error. maybe in your list comprehension window unpacks multiple walues when you assign only p? (if it wasn't the case window[0] wouldn't mean anything)

Comment: @PeterDolan I put the full stack trace in the post.

Comment: @bobrobbob window[0] does mean something because I have other programs that use this exact code and it works great in them. basically the formatData is copied and pasted from other code where it works fine. Can you explain more about unpacking and comprehension window?

Comment: in `normalised_window = [((float(p) / float(window[0])) - 1) for p in window]` p is not the only value in window (there's also window[0]).

Comment: @bobrobbob then what's the best solution? I got most of this code from a tutorial bc I'm very new to python, but my understanding is that the goal is to compare all the next windows to the original

Comment: @bobrobbob even if I remove the line where I normalize windows from formatData, I still get the same error when I run it

Comment: so it's probably the indexing then. like `x = result[:, :-1]`. if `normalised_data` is empty that's the error you'd have